# Past Text for multiple Select Input (R; Shiny)

Tags: r, shiny

I am working on a shiny app and created a simplified version of my problem below. Pretty much I want to have a input select of different options (A,B,C,D) and when any or all of these options are selected then prints out different texts. Currently, if I select all the options then only "Your Idael A Value is" posts.

```
library(shiny) 
shinyServer( function(input, output) {
  output$whatever<-renderText( {
    if( input$test=="a") {
      ("Your ideal A value is")
    }
    else if (input$test=="b") {
      ("Your ideal B value is:")
    }
    else if (input$test=="c") {
      ("Your ideal C value is:")
    }
    else if(input$test=="D") {
      ("Your idea D value is:")
    }
  }
  )
}

)
```

---

```
    library(shiny)

   shinyUI(fluidPage(
   headerPanel(title="pratice"),
   sidebarLayout(
   sidebarPanel(
   selectInput("test",label="Test",multiple = TRUE, 
   choices=list("a","b","c","d")
   )),
   mainPanel(
  textOutput("whatever")
  )
  )
  )
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

An if statement stops as soon as it encounters a valide statement.

No need for an if here, you can simple paste the input values together:

```
library(shiny) 
server <- shinyServer( function(input, output) {
  output$whatever<-renderText( {
    vals <- paste(input$test, collapse = " ")
    paste("Your ideal(s) value(s) are", vals)

  }
  )
}

)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  headerPanel(title="pratice"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("test",label="Test",multiple = TRUE, 
                  choices=list("a","b","c","d"), 
      )),
    mainPanel(
      textOutput("whatever")
    )
  )
)
)

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

```
 selectizeInput(inputId, label, choices, selected = NULL, multiple = FALSE,
           options = NULL) ## and switch multiple to True
```

Comment: You Jacob are a genius